# Python/numpy issue with array/vector with empty second dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector

I have what seems to be an easy question.

Observe the code:

```
In : x=np.array([0, 6])
Out: array([0, 6])
In : x.shape
Out: (2L,)
```

Which shows that the array has no second dimension, and therefore `x` is no differnet from `x.T`.

How can I make x have dimension (2L,1L)? The real motivation for this question is that I have an array `y` of shape `[3L,4L]`, and I want y.sum(1) to be a vector that can be transposed, etc.

Comment: NumPy arrays have a `reshape()` method or you can also add an extra dimension.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While you can reshape arrays, and add dimensions with `[:,np.newaxis]`, you should be familiar with the most basic nested brackets, or list, notation.  Note how it matches the display.

```
In [230]: np.array([[0],[6]])
Out[230]: 
array([[0],
       [6]])
In [231]: _.shape
Out[231]: (2, 1)
```

`np.array` also takes a `ndmin` parameter, though it add extra dimensions at the start (the default location for `numpy`.)

```
In [232]: np.array([0,6],ndmin=2)
Out[232]: array([[0, 6]])
In [233]: _.shape
Out[233]: (1, 2)
```

A classic way of making something 2d - reshape:

```
In [234]: y=np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [235]: y
Out[235]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

`sum` (and related functions) has a `keepdims` parameter.  Read the docs.

```
In [236]: y.sum(axis=1,keepdims=True)
Out[236]: 
array([[ 6],
       [22],
       [38]])
In [237]: _.shape
Out[237]: (3, 1)
```

`empty 2nd dimension` isn't quite the terminology.  More like a nonexistent 2nd dimension.

A dimension can have 0 terms:

```
In [238]: np.ones((2,0))
Out[238]: array([], shape=(2, 0), dtype=float64)
```

If you are more familiar with MATLAB, which has a minimum of 2d, you might like the `np.matrix` subclass.  It takes steps to ensure that most operations return another 2d matrix:

```
In [247]: ym=np.matrix(y)
In [248]: ym.sum(axis=1)
Out[248]: 
matrix([[ 6],
        [22],
        [38]])
```

The matrix `sum` does:

```
np.ndarray.sum(self, axis, dtype, out, keepdims=True)._collapse(axis)
```

The `_collapse` bit lets it return a scalar for `ym.sum()`.

Comment: Is there a way to have keepdims=True be the default? It's an awful lot to type again and again.

Comment: For me it seems that taking the transpose of a (2L,) array should make numpy realize you want a (1L,2L) array

Comment: There is the `np.matrix` class.

Comment: didn't know about keepdims, nice!

Answer (score 3):

There is another point to keep dimension info:

```
In [42]: X
Out[42]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1]])

In [43]: X[1].shape
Out[43]: (2,)

In [44]: X[1:2].shape
Out[44]: (1, 2)

In [45]: X[1]
Out[45]: array([0, 1])

In [46]: X[1:2]  # this way will keep dimension
Out[46]: array([[0, 1]])
```